# Replace all minus numbers with 0 Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

How can I replace all minus numbers with 0 in a particular column in PowerShell

I only want to examine the `quality` column on my CSV

Example Data:

```
Name      Colour    Quality
Apple     RED       5
Pear      Green     4
Plum      Purple    -3
Melon     Yellow    -1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should do what you want:

```
$data = import-csv [path]
$data  | ForEach-Object {
    $_.quality = $_.quality -replace  "-\d","0"
}
```

The regex pattern for replace specifies to replace minus followed by a digit (\d = 0-9)

result:

```
Name  Colour Quality
----  ------ -------
Apple RED    5
Pear  Green  4
Plum  Purple 0
Melon Yellow 0
```

Comment: Or `$data = import-csv [path]; $data.ForEach( {$_.Quality = $_.Quality -replace '-\d+', '0'} )`, see [ForEach and Where magic methods](https://powershellmagazine.com/2014/10/22/foreach-and-where-magic-methods/)

Comment: Or without regex: `$data | ForEach-Object { $_.quality = [math]::Max($_.quality, 0) }`

Comment: Thanks so much everyone.  I have the script working as it should now :)